# Manually multiplying two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I am using `R v 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)` and `RStudio v 1.1.463` under Win-7 64-bit.

In the following source code:

```
# Problem 1 - Matrix powers in R
#
# R does not have a built-in command for taking matrix powers. 
# Write a function matrixpower with two arguments mat and k that 
# will take integer powers k of a matrix mat.
matrixMul <- function(mat1)
{
  rows <- nrow(mat1)
  cols <- ncol(mat1)

  matOut = matrix(nrow = rows, ncol = cols) # empty matrix

  for (i in 1:rows) 
  {
    for(j in 1:cols)
    {
      vec1 <- mat1[i,]
      vec2 <- mat1[,j]

      mult1 <- vec1 * vec2

      matOut[i,j] <- mult1
    }
  }

  return(matOut) 
}

mat1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2, ncol=2)    
power1 <- matrixMul(mat1)
```

According to matrix multiplication rule, the desired output is:

```
7    10
15   22
```

But, I am getting the following output:

```
3    12
6    16
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Is this an efficient way of doing multiplication?

Comment: R has built-in matrix multiplication using %*%. That might be simpler than using a for-loop. Ex: mat1 %*% mat1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found the solution.

```
matrixMul <- function(mat1)
{
  rows <- nrow(mat1)
  cols <- ncol(mat1)

  matOut <- matrix(nrow = rows, ncol = cols) # empty matrix

  for (i in 1:rows) 
  {
    for(j in 1:cols)
    {
      vec1 <- mat1[i,]
      vec2 <- mat1[,j]

      mult1 <- vec1 * vec2

      matOut[i,j] <- sum(mult1)
    }
  }

  return(matOut) 
}


mat1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2, ncol=2)
mult1 <- matrixMul(mat1)
mult1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you forget to sum your product. It should be

`mult1 <- sum(vec1 * vec2)`

Perhaps in your version of `R` it is otherwise just assigning the first element of the vector.